# Storing negative int value in an unsigned bit and subtracting from it

Tags: c, int, unsigned, negative-number

First of all I've been searching for the outcome of a negative input in an unsigned int but can't find out how it is converted. Like for example -3. How does -3 look like and how did it turn out like that?

How about subtracting from it?

What will happen?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){ 
unsigned int num1 = 3, num2 = -2; 

printf("num1's initial value is %u.\n",num1); 
printf("num2's initial value is %u.\n",num2); 

num1 = num1 + 1; 
num2 = num2 - 1; 

printf("num1's value is now %u.\n",num1); 
printf("num2's value is now %u.\n",num2); 

num1 = 2147483647; 
num2 = -2147483648; 

printf("num1's value is now %u.\n",num1); 
printf("num2's value is now %u.\n",num2); 

num1 = num1 + 1; 
num2 = num2 - 1; 

printf("num1's value is now %u.\n",num1); 
printf("num2's value is now %u.\n",num2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you have the code... what happened ?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti that post is only about assigning the negative value to the unsigned int. Here, I want to know about what happens when you subtract or add to it. I can't find answers anywhere even in Google.

Comment: You first assign a negative value (or you read it), result after an arithmetic operation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056758/c-c-unsigned-integer-overflow (it doesn't matter if it was negative or not, it overflows as usual).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The negative value to assign is converted to the unsigned type as if by repeated addition or subtraction of `TYPE_MAX + 1`, until it is in range. Two's complement does not come into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Let's go line by line..

1 . `unsigned int num1 = 3, num2 = -2;`

for `num2 = -2 ;` It will show as a positive integer of value of
max unsigned integer - 1 (value depends on computer architecture and compiler).

like if you assign num2 = X (say) and the stored value will be MAX_UNSIGNED_VALUE - (X-1).

Basically It will assign the bit pattern representing -X (in 2's complement) to the unsigned int. Which will be a large unsigned value. For 32 bit ints this will be 2^32 - (X+1).

Next the line

```
num2 = -2147483648;
```

So I'm considering 32 bit int it will store the (max value of an unsigned int - 2147483647). that is

num2 = (4294967295-2147483647) = 2147483648

Very detailed explanation about how this conversion happens is given, in the following articles.

- [Unsigned Binary](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/unsigned.html)
- [A tutorial on signed and unsigned integers](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/08/a-tutorial-on-signed-and-unsigned-integers/)
- [Unsigned and Signed Integers](http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/13.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. :D

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a negative number is the same as assigning 0 and subtracting that number. When this subtraction occurs, your number overflows and becomes huge;

If x is the bigger number you can store, x + 1 = 0 (overflows and goes around in a loop), which means that when you perform 0 - 1 in an unsigned number, you're actually getting the biggest number you can store.

Only when you subtract beyond 0 or sum beyond the max number the things behave differently. After that those numbers will behave like any others.

Comment: This answer explains well unsigned integers.  Other possibilities occur with signed integers.