# What happens to a value assigned to take up more than a types available space?

Tags: c++, memory, uint8t

e.g.

```
uint8_t value = 256;
```

debug output:

```
0
```

I've read that it does some sort of truncating? I'm not seeing exactly how, any links are appreciated.

Comment: dupe/related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056758/c-c-unsigned-integer-overflow

Comment: Who is voting to close this as *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to make sense of it along with you.

`uint8_t` is an 8-bit data type, or a byte.  It has 8 slots which can either be `1` or `0`.  `1111 1111` would be 255.  So if you ad one to it, it keeps carrying over.  255 + 1 in binary would be `1 0000 0000`, but since the data type can only store 8 bits, it drops the 1, and becomes `0000 0000`, which translates to the integer value `0`.

At least, that's how I understand it works.

Answer (score 3):

According to [conv.integral]

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer (modulo 2^`n` where `n` is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ *Note:* In a two’s
>   complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there
>   is no truncation). — *end note* ]
>
> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
>   bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

So, for your example, you would reliably get zero; if you used `int8_t` instead of `uint8_t`, the result would be implementation-defined. (In contrast, if an operation on signed integers *overflows*, the result is undefined behaviour. Why the inconsistency? I don't know.)

Comment: As for the "Why?" see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is

Answer (score 1):

In the case of unsigned integral types, the lowest appropriate number of bits get stored in the variable. (Brian's answer encompasses everything that I say here.)

For example, `unsigned char a = 257` would result in `a=1`.

The compiler (`gcc` in this case) should warn you when you do such assignments, e.g. `filename.c:line:column: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]`.