# Using unsigned data types in C

Tags: c, int, unsigned

How to use unsigned int properly? My function `unsigned int sub(int num1, int num2);`doesn't work when user input `a` is less than `b`. If I simply use int, we can expect a negative answer and I need to determine which is larger before subtracting. I know that's easy but maybe there is a way to use unsigned int to avoid that?

For instance when `a` = 7 and `b` = 4, the answer is 3.000000. But when I flip them, the code gives me 4294967296.000000 which I think is a memory address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int sub(int num1,int num2){
    unsigned int diff = 0;
    diff = num1 - num2;
    return diff;
}

int main(){
    printf("sub(7,4) = %u\n", sub(7,4));
    printf("sub(4,7) = %u\n", sub(4,7));
}
```

output:

```
sub(7,4) = 3
sub(4,7) = 4294967293
```

Comment: Converting from signed to unsigned doesn't result in taking the absolute value. It results in a [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) conversion.

Comment: What did you expect to get from the a=4, b=7 case?

Comment: @Cornstalks ahh you're right, absolute value must be the best way to do it

Comment: Almost none of the posted code is at all relevant, and the bit that _is_ relevant depends on user input you didn't show. At least say what output you want.

Comment: @M.M I expect -3 but since it is unsigned, maybe it will drop the negative sign? Now that I think about it, maybe I misunderstood unsigned data types

Comment: Yeah, `unsigned` means _without a sign_, which means it can't be negative. If you need to allow negative values, you can't use `unsigned`. Out of interest, what did you think it meant?

Comment: Good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056758/c-c-unsigned-integer-overflow

Comment: @Cornstalks: Only for 2's complement representation.

Comment: @useless im sorry, still figuring out the MCVE practice. I thought it would simply drop the negative sign, but after my quick research, it basically translates the whole int range into the right of 0.

Comment: You want [`abs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) for that. Using unsigned gives you the underflow behaviour described in the linked question and some of the answers. And, no problem - have a worked example of writing an MCVE.

Comment: @Useless wow thanks for editing. From how you edited my code, I take it that I don't need to present my hard code but only the essence.

Comment: @Olaf: No, not just for 2's complement representation. The conversion from signed to unsigned is well defined, and is effectively a modular arithmetic conversion. For example, a signed `int` variable `n` converted to `unsigned int` results in a positive value that is equivalent to `n` modulo `UINT_MAX+1`. [Example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-12+mod+2%5E32)

Comment: @Cornstalks: Ok, my fault, it is just "for free" (i.e. without extra operations) on 2's complement architectures, but has the same semantics on all three encodings.

Comment: It's possible for `num1 - num2` to overflow (if `num1` and `num2` are of type `int`). For safety, you can use `if (num2 > num1) diff = (unsigned)num2 - (unsigned)num1; else diff = (unsigned)num1 - (unsigned)num2;` to get the absolute difference with no integer overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsigned numbers are *unsigned*... This means that they *cannot* be negative.
Instead they wrap (underflow or overflow).

If you do an experiment with an 8-bit unsigned, then you can see the effect of subtracting `1` from `0`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t i;

    i = 1;

    printf("i: %hhu\n", i);

    i -= 1;

    printf("i: %hhu\n", i);

    i -= 1;

    printf("i: %hhu\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

```
i: 1
i: 0
i: 255
```

`255` is the largest value that an 8-bit unsigned can hold (`2^8 - 1`).

---

We can then do the same experiment with a 32-bit unsigned, using your `4 - 7`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint32_t i;

    i = 4;

    printf("i: %u\n", i);

    i -= 7;

    printf("i: %u\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

```
i: 4
i: 4294967293
```

`4294967293` is effectively `0 - 3`, which wraps to `2^32 - 3`.

---

You also need to be careful of assigning an integer value (the return type of your `sub()` function) to a `float`... Generally this is something to avoid.

See below. `x()` returns `4294967293` as an `unsigned int`, but it is stored in a `float`... This `float` is then printed as `4294967296`???

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned int x(void) {
    return 4294967293U;
}

int main(void) {
    float y;

    y = x();

    printf("y: %f\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

```
y: 4294967296.000000
```

This is actually to do with the precision of `float`... it is impossible to store the absolute value `4294967293` in a `float`.

Comment: thank you for that very detailed explanation. Can I ask what type of identifier `uint8_t` is?

Comment: @reiallenramos `uint8_t` is an unsigned integer type exactly 8 bits wide defined by `#include <stdint.h>`. It is optional if the implementation has no such type available.

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned int` cannot be used to represent a negative variable.  I believe what you wanted is to find the absolute value of the difference between `a` and `b`.  If so, you can use the `abs()` function from `stdlib.h`.  The `abs()` function takes in an `int` variable `i` and returns the absolute value of `i`.

The reason why `unsigned int` returns a huge number in your case is due to the way integers are represented in the system.  You declared `diff` as an `int` type, which is capable of storing a negative value, but the same sequence of bits that represents `-3` when interpreted as `unsigned int` represents `4294967296` instead.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is called *unsigned integer overflow*. As you noted, unsigned integers can't hold negative numbers. So when you try to do something that would result in a negative number, seemingly weird things can occour.

If you work with 32-bit integers,

- int (`int32_t`) can hold numbers between (-2^31) and (+2^31-1), `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`
- unsigned int (`uint32_t`) can hold numbers between (0) and (2^32-1), `UINT_MIN` and `UINT_MAX`

When you try to add something to an int that would lead to a number greater than the type can hold, it will **overflow**.

Comment: this is good info but it didn't answer my question, so I can't choose this as _the_ answer

Comment: @reiallenramos What do you want? To print a `unsigned` value as -3?

Comment: @chux no, I wanted to drop the - sign, which has been solved already by using abs() from the other comments

Comment: @reiallenramos `abs()` has its [problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43476048/2410359) too.

Comment: @chux like what? For my purposes, I just sticked to the int declaration and then used abs() down in the function definition.

Comment: @reiallenramos Taking the `abs()` issues to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43476048/2410359)

Answer (score 0):

It becomes a negative number, unsigned data types dont hold negative number, so instead it becomes a large number

Answer (score 0):

"absolute value of the difference between a and b" does not work for many combinations of `a,b`.  Any `a-b` that overflows is undefined behavior.  Obviously `abs(INT_MAX - INT_MIN)` will not generate the correct answer.

Also, using `abs()` invokes undefined behavior with a select value of `int`.  `abs(INT_MIN)` is undefined behavior when `-INT_MIN` is not representable as an `int`.

To calculate the absolute value difference of 2 `int`, subtract them as `unsigned`.

```
unsigned int abssub(int num1,int num2){
  return (num1 > num2) ? (unsigned) num1 - num2 : (unsigned) num2 - num1;
}
```