# for (unsigned char i = 0; i<=0xff; i++) produces infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, unsigned-char

Why does the following c code end up in an infinite loop?

```
for(unsigned char i = 0; i <= 0xff; i++){}
```

It is the same result with:

```
for(unsigned char i = 0; i <= 0xff; ++i){}
```

In which way do I have to modify the code, to get it working as expected (without using `int` or `unsigned int` datatype)?

Comment: Do you understand what a unsigned number is?

Comment: It's not possible for an 8 bit `unsigned char` to store a value larger than `0xff`, therefore, it's impossible for `i <= 0xff` to be `false`.

Comment: Your two examples are identical. I would assume they have the same result.

Comment: Use an `int`. Don't put stupid restrictions on what answers are acceptable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16056758/1896169

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: No, they aren't identical. One uses `i++`, the other uses `++i`. (It's true that they're identical in effect, since the result is discarded.)

Comment: Note that if you were compiling with `-Wextra`, gcc would have issued a warning for your loop, explaining the condition is always true due to data type limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical `for` loop relies on being able to detect the termination condition *after* the last iteration of the loop. In your case, as other answers have pointed out, `i <= 0xff` is always true (given that `i` is of type `unsigned char` and that `UCHAR_MAX==0xff`, which is typical).

You can run into the same kind of problem near the bounds of any integer type. For example, this:

```
for (int i = INT_MAX - 9; i <= INT_MAX; i ++) {
    /* ... */
}
```

is (probably) also an infinite loop (except that overflow for signed integer types has undefined behavior as opposed to the well-defined wraparound semantics for unsigned integers, and an optimizing compiler can take advantage of that and -- but I digress).  Just don't do that.

One of many solutions is to move the test to the *bottom* of the loop, before the increment:

```
for (unsigned char i = 0; ; i ++) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if (i == 0xff) break;
}
```

The second clause of a `for` loop is the termination condition, evaluated before each iteration.  If you leave it empty, it's treated as always true, giving you an infinite loop (`for (;;)` is a common idiom for a simple infinite loop).  We test whether `i` is **equal** to `0xff` at the bottom of the loop. If it is then we've just executed the last iteration, and we can break out of the loop.

(Some might prefer to use a `while` loop here, but I like the `for` because it lets us combine the declaration of the loop control variable and the increment in a single construct.)

(Strictly speaking the maximum value of `unsigned char` isn't necessarily `0xff` or `255`, but it will be on any system you're likely to encounter. Implementations for some DSPs have `CHAR_BIT > 8`, and thus `UCHAR_MAX > 255`.)

Answer (score 18):

If you really need to use `unsigned char` then you can use

```
unsigned char i = 0;
do {
    // ... 
} while(++i);
```

When an arithmetic operation on an `unsigned` integer breaks its limits, the behaviour is well defined. So this solution will process 256 values (for 8-bit `unsigned char`).

Comment: Well I be damned, another rare use of a do while loop.

Comment: @StoryTeller same! I always thought do-while loops were made only for defining multi line macros!

Comment: @StoryTeller another `do-while` usage is when converting an integer to a string in a loop, where the output `"0"` is wanted when the input is `0` but needs to terminate when `value /= 10` *becomes* `0`.

Answer (score 8):

The range of an `unsigned char` is 0 to 255 (0xff).  Adding 1 to 0xff makes 0x100, which when assigned back to an `unsigned char` wraps around back to 0.

So the comparison `i <= 0xff` will always be true.  Hence the infinite loop.

If you want the loop to stop after 0xff, use `int` as the datatype.  This is a range of at least -32767 to 32767, and typically more.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps OP should remove *(without using `int` or `unsigned int` datatype)* from the question.

Comment: "The range of an unsigned char is 0 to 255 (0xff)." on some platforms.

Comment: Nitpick: the minimum required range of `int` is actually `-32767` to `32767` (to allow for one's complement machines)

Comment: Detail: "Adding 1 to 0xff will wraparound back to 0" --> adding 1 to 0xFF will result in 256, an `int`.  It is the assignment of 256 back to the `unsigned char` that is handle _like_ unsigned "overflow" and assign 0 to `i` due to an assignment conversion.

Comment: @chux Good point.  Edited to reflect, and fixed the minimum range of an `int`.

Comment: @AndrewSun: Meta-nitpick: to allow for one's complement *and sign-and-magnitude* machines. And also two's complement machines that treat the most negative value as a trap representation.

Comment: @Slava _on some platforms_ ?? On some platforms is not. I would say nowadays only specialised old DSP processors only.

Comment: @Andrew Sun _to allow for one's complement machines_ do know any younger than 30y? And sign and magnitude younger than 50y?

Comment: @PeterJ so what? C++ does not guarantee that byte has 8 bits, so you need to mention that range is on machines that have it.

Comment: @Slava did you ever worked on the machine which has a char != 8bit. I personally did not and I do this job for 30+ years. But if I have to write a firmware for a DSP processor the portability of the code will by the least important issue.

Comment: @PeterJ from language point of view that the case, it needs to be mentioned. If you need to write portable code or you meet such platform or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Programming is a very practical science. Practically your remarks have absolutely no value - because the probability of having any contact with implementation where char != 8 bits is almost zero, and it can be treated as an exemption from the common rule. Such a divagations  are purely scholastic.

Answer (score 2):

Because you wraparound. An unsigned char values range between 0-255, and because unsigned arithmetic are well defind, you actually wrap the value of `i` to 0 and the condition is still met and the iteration continues ad infinitum.

In the case of signed values, it is an undefined behaviour and value stored in i might not be 0. But still it will be smaller than the maximum value you could store in a char and the condition is still met.

Comment: no, overflowing unsigned integers is well defined; they wrap under modulo arithmetic.

Comment: The `unsigned` value does not overflow, it wraps. A `signed` value would overflow.

Comment: There is no addition or arithmetic "overflow" issue.  There is a similar issue though, that of assigning 256 to an `unsigned char`.  Same result, `i` is 0.

Comment: "In the case of signed values" does not apply here.  The value is going from 0 to 255 to 256 (for a moment)  to 0...  There are no signed values - they are all non-negative.  If you are considering signed types for `i`, the answers differs if `i` is `int` or sub-`int`.  One is UB the other IDB/exception.

Comment: @chux it was only said for the undefined behavior, so that if he uses the great solution proposed by WeatherVane, he needs to know signed values might not wrap to 0 and the do-while won't work as expected.