# Why the unsigned integer produces a big output when the number stored through cin is negative?

Tags: c++, int, unsigned

I want to know how the unsigned integer works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 50;             //basic integer data type
    unsigned int b;         //unsigned means the variable only holds positive values
    cout << "How many hours do you work? ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Your wage is " << b << " pesos.";

}
```

But when I enter -5, the output is

```
Your wage is 4294967291 pesos.
```

And when I enter -1, the output is

```
Your wage is 4294967295 pesos.
```

Supposedly, unsigned integers hold positive values. How does this happen?
And I only know basic C++. I don't understand bits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ unsigned integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056758/c-c-unsigned-integer-overflow)

Comment: "_Supposedly, unsigned integers hold positive values_" Sure, they hold positive values. Your output is positive, so why do you think, that unsigned integers hold anything more, than positive values?

Comment: You should check if `cin >> b;` fails.

Comment: It's also entertaining, btw, when the `int` is negative (especially a near-zero negative number), against a properly read `unsigned int`. The promotions may surprise you.

Comment: @Eljay, good advice, but if you interpret the bits of 4294967291 as a 32-bit signed int, you get -5.  Coincidence? or did the `>>` operator succeed (for some definition of "succeed.")

Comment: It never fails. I ran it and that was the output.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser That's pointless, and incurs a runtime cost.

Comment: @jameslarge • implementation dependent partially succeeded, but actually failed.  GIGO when ignoring failure checking, unless one has reason to believe the data is valid (but in this case, we know /a priori/ that we're throwing bad data at the input).

Comment: @lubgr, it is not a duplicate and it will never be since I did not understand integer security. I only understand basic C++ programming and never delved into bits of code since it wasn't taught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversion from signed to unsigned integer is done by the following rule (§[conv.integral]):

> 1. A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another
>      integer type.
>    [...]
> 2. If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting
>      value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer
>      (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where *n* is the number of bits used to represent the
>      unsigned type).

In your case, `unsigned` is apparently a 32-bit type, so -5 is being reduced modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. So 2<sup>32</sup> = 4,294,967,296 and 4,294,967,296 - 5 = 4,294,967,291.