# Can anyone explain this code behaviour in c++?

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> a(10);
vector<int> b(20);

if ((a.size() - b.size()) > 1) {
    cout << "yes";
}
```

Can anyone explain why this code prints "yes". If I try storing a.size() - b.size() in an int variable, it is working as expected.

Comment: Note the return type of `std::vector<T>::size()`.

Comment: `size()` returns an unsigned value. `10 - 20` will wrap around to a very large value. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056758/c-c-unsigned-integer-overflow

Comment: a.size()-b.size()>1 is similar to a.size()!=b.size()